# Custom button/menu button on quick create form in CRM 2013

Tags: customization, dynamics-crm-2013

Is it possible put extra button to quick create form in CRM 2013?
I have std ribbon button in std form to acquire info about company from internet. I want similar button in quic create form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ribbon support in Quick Create forms.  I would therefore add a button to the Quick Create form using an HTML web resource which performs the same action (JavaScript?) as that on the existing ribbon button you've already created.

If this feature must be available on both forms I would for UI consistency use the same web resource approach on the Quick Create and Main forms rather than one button in the ribbon and one on the form as a web resource.

Comment: Yes. Easy and functional. Thanks.